# Java byteArray[] to docx

Tags: java, byte, docx, doc

doc file in `byte[]` type. 
Is it possible to convert it from byte[] into .docx file.

tried just change file extension programilly but it does not work.
any suggestions?

I generate report using BiRT eclipse
code of saving doc:

```
options = new RenderOptionBase();
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
options.setOutputStream(bos);
options.setOutputFormat("doc");
if(parameters != null){
    task.setParameterValues(parameters);
}
task.setRenderOption(options);
task.run();

return bos.toByteArray()

//IRunAndRenderTask task;
```

problem is that we use BIRT 3.7 which not support `DocxRenderOption`

Comment: Could you show some code please? How you read/write the file for example

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/20c12183-78bb-43d1-8c1d-53b89f5818da/byte-array-to-docx-file?forum=silverlightnet

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at Aspose.Words for Java -- http://www.aspose.com/java/word-component.aspx

It has really good doc too -- http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsjava/load+or+create+a+document

Code will be as simple as

// Open a document.

Document doc = new Document("input.doc");

// Save document.

doc.save("output.docx");

Step1: save the doc file 
Step2: using this lib convert the file and save as docx file.

Comment: it is not free... if I understand well